# How can I assign different elements in an array to different text boxes C#

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms

I have an array with 100 elements that I want to assign to 100 text boxes in a windows form.  The issue is the array is not sorted in a useful manner so a for loop won't work.

The only thing I can think of is to write 100 lines of code that assign the correct array element to the correct textbox but that seems like a horrible way of doing it.

A quick example of the how the array is formatted is below:

```
10  Air Temperature #1,           1 Minute Run Average     Celsius  Minute 59-60
11  Humidity,                     1 Minute Run Average           %  Minute 59-60
12  Air Temperature #1,          60 Minute Run Average     Celsius  Minute 00-60
13  Air Temperature #1,      Max(1 Minute Run Average)     Celsius  Minute 00-60
14  Humidity,                Max(1 Minute Run Average)           %  Minute 00-60
15  Air Temperature #1,      Min(1 Minute Run Average)     Celsius  Minute 00-60
16  Humidity,                Min(1 Minute Run Average)           %  Minute 00-60
```

As you can see, Air Temperature is split up, further down the array are Air Temperature #2 values, but I want all Temperature data to be together.

Comment: I suspect you might be better off with a listbox or gridview and a method of sorting, but it's impossible to really tell based on your description of the problem.  You say "array", but we don't know what it is an array OF.  Strings?  Or whether the textboxes already exist (or you are creating them dynamically), or if they have control names that somehow relate to the data you want to put in them...

Comment: You can use linq `OrderBy` to sort your array in a usefull manner by specifying a sub-string to order by `var sorted = array.OrderBy(i => i.Substring(18)).ToList() `

Comment: I usually change names of textboxes to be meaningful.  In some cases I make a List<TextBoxes> then add to the list the textboxes in the order you need.  The index of the List<> item would be the index number of your current array.

Answer (score 0):

Create a class which represent your data in one item

```
class MeasureData
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string AverageData { get; set; }
    public string Unit { get; set; }
    public string Minutes{ get; set; }
}
```

Instead of textboxes use `DataGridView` control.
Create collection of data and add collection as `DataSource` to the `DataGridView`

```
var data = new MeasureData[]
{
    new MeasureData
    {
        Id = 10,
        Description = "Air Temperature #1",
        AverageData = "1 Minute Run Average",
        Unit = "Celsius",
        Minutes = "Minute 59-60"
    },
    new MeasureData
    {
        Id = 11,
        Description = "Humidity",
        AverageData = "1 Minute Run Average",
        Unit = "%",
        Minutes = "Minute 59-60"
    }
    // and so on
};

myDataGridView.DataSource = data;
```

If you want sort data before adding to `DataGridView` use LINQ to sort it

```
var sortedData = data.OrderBy(item => item.Id).ToArray();
```

`DataGridView` will generate rows for every item in the array, and columns for every property in the class `MeasureData`.
If you want to show only some of the properties, then create columns manually with `DataGridViewColumn.DataPropertyName = "NameOfThePropertyYouWantToShow"` and remember set `DataGridView.AutoGenerateColumns = false`, because by default it is `true`